# How to proceed to Repopulate a Dropzone Div with Old Input In Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, dropzone.js

Im making a Post form with inputs along with a dropzone Div to upload Photos,

My issue is the following: As Im pushing all the photos to a session until the moment I persist the relation with the post, I dont know exactly how to proceed when some field is Not being filled.
I need to go back and present the form again.

The problem is that all my dropzone photos are being emptied from the form but not from the session. so if I correctly fill the form again and submit the data I will have more photos persisted than they should.

So I was thinking in making an event about some Request has failed(not filled all inputs) then flush the session Photo field.

But I dont know how is represented the fact that this Request has failed, or should I Repopulate the dropzone Div with eg.Input:old.

Can anybody address me or making a suggestion please.

Answer (score 2):

Flushing the session is not a good idea in my opinion. A user who uploaded images will have to do it again when form validation fails. It is better to repopulate them.

**The solution**

You can add images below your dropzone input in your form and they will be populated as uploaded images. You only need a HTML structure.

In order get HTML structure, you can upload one image (drag n drop in your dropzone), inspect the uploaded image with developer tools and copy the generated code.

The only thing you will have to do, is to add all photos to an array on the server side.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="photos" class="dropzone">
    <input name="file" type="file">

    @foreach ($uploadedPhotos as $uploadedPhoto)
        <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success">
            <div class="dz-details">
                <img data-dz-thumbnail=""
                  src="{{ $uploadedPhoto['src'] }}"
                  class="@if ($uploadedPhoto['vertical']) vertical @endif">
            </div>
            <div class="dz-progress">
                <span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress="" style="width: 100%;"></span>
             </div>
             <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>?</span></div>

             <a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove image</a>
         </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

You might need to play a little with css or js to style it and make other things functional e.g. remove button.

Comment: Hello @Dovis and thanks for replying. I ended up using a guid as this article refers.   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-dropzone-how-do-i-store-article-id-in-images-table-before-that-article-has-been-created. Also I had to play around with the init: function () { to use a mockfile if the user doesnt fill all the fields, so it will repopulate the dropzone. like  http://www.chinabtp.com/how-do-i-preload-images-into-dropzone-js/. I think your idea is also good but i wouldnt like to have another div for dropzone if something goes wrong, i would prefer to use the existing